# Unity circular sector prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics

I need to create prefab, that will allow me to spawn many objects of shape of circular sector with given radius and angle. How to do it?

Comment: Please try to be more specific. What is the desired output? a mesh? or are you trying to modifiy an existing mesh? Did you try something?

Comment: @Toaster, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since the shapes you want are simple, but chosen dynamically, I think the easiest solution is to have a script create the meshes on the fly when you instanciate your prefab.

Your prefab needs to have a MeshFilter and a custom script. This script will have to compute the vertices that you want (I suppose that you know how to compute the vertices using radius and angle) and assign them to the Mesh.
See the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) for a complete example on how to use the Mesh class.

You can also find an example project using procedural meshes [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/?&_ga=2.136056185.930167652.1515402491-1755883373.1513067733#!/content/5141)